# Split dictionary into two sub-dictionaries using a string

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I want to split it into two sub-dictioaries based on a string.

Is there a nicer (more pythonic) way to do it than this:

```
dict_1 = {k:v for (k,v) in initial_dict.iteritems() if string in k}
dict_2 = {k:v for (k,v) in initial_dict.iteritems() if string not in k}
```

Comment: What  your dict looks like? what is the expected result?

Comment: You can use a single loop and break with a single `if / else` instead of iterating trough `initial_dict` twice.  But in reality any performance gain isn't going to be noticeable unless you're dealing with lots of entries, and even then the readability is probably of more value here.  This is more likely better solved at the point that `initial_dict` is first built.

Comment: The key is a string (username) and the value is a tuple of {date_in, date_out}.

I want to have two dictionaries, one containing all entries for a specific username and all other username into another dictionary.

Comment: Do you want to keep `initial_dict` as it is, or is it ok to mutate it?

Comment: Key's are unique, isn't there just one entry for a specific username?

Comment: @PM 2Ring - No, I don't need the initial_dict after the split.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict_1 = {key:initial_dict.pop(key) for key in initial_dict if string in key}
dict_2 = initial_dict
```

Comment: Need to create a copy with `dict(initial_dict)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Sorry I incorrectly assumed it was okay to mutate the initial_dict.

Comment: It's a Good Idea™ to add _some_ explanation to your code on SO, even when the code seems obvious to you. Answers should help not only the OP but also future readers. FWIW, some regulars will down-vote code-only answers as a matter of principle, since answers are supposed to explain stuff, not merely show how it's done. (I prefer to leave comments & only use down-votes as a last resort). Also,  code-only answers can be harder to find via search engines.

Comment: you can do `dict_2=initial_dict.copy()` as the first line and then substitute `dict_2` for `initial_dict` in the dict comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

I'll vote for your original. Clear, short, and only slightly inefficient

There *is* a way to do it without referencing or testing elements of initial_dict more than once, which is quite Pythonic if Pythonic means knowing that `int(False)==0` and `int(True)==1`

```
dict1, dict2 = {}, {}
for k,v in initial_dict.items(): (dict2,dict1)[string in k][k] = v
```

Like I said, I prefer the questioner's way!

By the way, if you have to perform an n-way partition, `dict_list[i][key]=v` inside a loop that fetches or generates key,i and v starts to look a lot better than a multi-way `if ... elif ... elif ...`

Comment: I prefer your way, since it doesn't require two passes over the `dict`. But I'd split that `for` loop over two lines, it's not like there's a global whitespace shortage. :) Also I agree with your remarks about `dict_list[i]` being better than a long `if...elif...` thing. It's more compact and it's (probably) more efficient since it (probably) avoids performing tests.

Comment: I always prefer loops over just one short(ish) statement on just one line. Vertical space on one's screen is a precious resource, and I like to see as much as possible of the code while coding provided it doesn't become horizontally uglified. Probably just personal taste. (Likewise `if condition: statement`)

Comment: Tongue firmly in cheek: if the BDFL hadn't intended us to write one-line loops he wouldn't have given us  the ability to put a statement after the colon.

Comment: Sure, and I used to do it to, especially with `break` & `continue`. But I've seen the error of my ways. :) (although I still do it when I'm just playing around in the interactive interpreter). It really makes the control flow a *lot* more visually obvious if you follow the [PEP008 style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) and don't put stuff on the same line after the colon.